# passing variables between two python decorators

Tags: python, decorator, chaining

Is there are a way to pass a variable between two python decorators applied to the same function? The goal is for one of the decorators to know that the other was also applied. I need something like decobar_present() from the example below:

```
def decobar(f):
    def wrap():
        return f() + "bar"
    return wrap

def decofu(f):
    def wrap():
        print decobar_present() # Tells me whether decobar was also applied
        return f() + "fu"
    return wrap

@decofu
@decobar
def important_task():
    return "abc"
```

More generally I would like to be able to modify the behavior of decofu depending on whether decobar was also applied.

Comment: Why do you need this? What are these decorators doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the function to a "registry" when `decobar` is applied to it, then later check the registry to determine whether `decobar` was applied to the function or not. This approach requires preserving original function's `__module__` and `__name__` properties intact (use `functools.wraps` over the wrapper function for that).

```
import functools

class decobar(object):
    registry = set()

    @classmethod
    def _func_key(cls, f):
        return '.'.join((f.__module__, f.func_name))

    @classmethod
    def present(cls, f):
        return cls._func_key(f) in cls.registry

    def __call__(self, f):
        self.registry.add(self._func_key(f))

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrap():
            return f() + "bar"
        return wrap

# Make the decorator singleton
decobar = decobar()

def decofu(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrap():
        print decobar.present(f) # Tells me whether decobar was also applied
        return f() + "fu"
    return wrap

@decofu
@decobar
def important_task():
    return "abc"
```

Used a class to implement `decobar`, as it keeps `registry` and `present()` in a single namespace (which feels slighly cleaner, IMO)

Comment: I think I will implement a central registry for all decorators. Thanks for the ideas above!

Answer (score 2):

To pass a variable between two python decorators you can use the decorated function's keyword arguments dictionary. Only don't forget to pop the added argument from there before calling the function from within the second decorator.

```
    def decorator1(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['cat_says'] = 'meow'
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

    def decorator2(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            print(kwargs.pop('cat_says'))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap


    class C:
        @decorator1
        @decorator2
        def spam(self, a, b, c, d=0):
            print("Hello, cat! What's your favourite number?")
            return a + b + c + d

    x=C()
    print(x.spam(1, 2, 3, d=7))
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do things like manipulate the [stack trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), you're better off, I think, simply creating a function `decofubar` and incorporate as much of both "fu" and "bar" as possible. At a minimum, it will make your code cleaner and more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Each decorator gets to wrap another function. The function passed to `decofu()` is the result of the `decobar()` decorator.

Just test for specific traits of the `decobar` wrapper, provided you make the wrapper recognisable:

```
def decobar(f):
    def wrap():
        return f() + "bar"
    wrap.decobar = True
    return wrap

def decofu(f):
    def wrap():
        print 'decobar!' if getattr(f, 'decobar') else 'not decobar'
        return f() + "fu"
    return wrap
```

I used an arbitrary attribute on the wrapper function, but you could try to test for a name (not so unambiguous), for the signature (using `inspect.getargspec()` perhaps), etc.

This is limited to *direct wrapping* only.

Generally speaking, you don't want to couple decorators as tightly as all this. Work out a different solution and only depend on function signature or return values.

Comment: Note: This only works if there are no other decorators between `decofu` and `decobar`.

Comment: @user2357112: Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign flag to `f` (or rather `wrap`) in `decobar` just like this

```
def decobar(f):
    def wrap():
        return f() + "bar"
    wrap.decobar_applied = True
    return wrap

def decofu(f):
    def wrap():
        if hasattr(f, 'decobar_applied') and f.decobar_applied:
            print decobar_present() # Tells me whether decobar was also applied
        return f() + "fu"
    return wrap

@decofu
@decobar
def important_task():
    return "abc"
```