# Problem with adding role based access decorator to the Flask function

Tags: flask

I want to implement role based access to resources, for that purpose i have decorator functions:

```
def permission_required(permission):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                return jsonify({'message' : 'You dont have right permission!'}), 401
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator

def admin_required(f):
    return permission_required(Permission.ADMIN)(f)

def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None
        if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-token']
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is missing !!'}), 401
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=["HS256"])
            current_user = db_session.query(Account).filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({
                'message' : 'Token is invalid !!'
            }), 401
        return  f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

which are called above test function:

```
@auth.route('/testing', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
@admin_required
def testing(current_user):
    
    print(current_user.can(Permission.ADMIN))
    return "successful"
```

@token_required function works fine but when I add @admin_required decorator it fails and throws

```
following error:
 File "/home/pi/backend/src/api/auth.py", line 43, in decorated
    return  f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/backend/src/api/auth.py", line 19, in decorated_function
    if not current_user.can(permission):
NameError: name 'current_user' is not defined
```

Kindly, advice what's wrong and how can I fix that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing variables between two python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748998/passing-variables-between-two-python-decorators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is the following:

```
def permission_required(permission):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(current_user, *args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                return jsonify({'message' : 'You dont have right permission!'}), 401
            return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```